# Exponents and Logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I'm lost on how to solve this for z. Can anyone help?

$\left(7^\left(-2z\right)\right)^\left(7-z\right) = 49^\left(-12\right)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to $7^{(-2x)(7-x)}=7^{2\cdot(-12)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\log_{7}$ of both sides and then simplify.

Answer (score 2):

Write $7^{-2z}$ as $(7^2)^{-z} = 49^{-z}$